# simple html and css assistance

Tags: html, css

i have a logo called gif.gif, what i am trying to do is position it on the top left corner. At the moment there is a gap, i want no padding or margins.

This is my html and css

**CSS**

```
#header, .img 
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Footer Stylings -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="https://www.google.co.uk"/><img src="gif.gif"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `body {margin: 0;}` and consider using a [reset](http://cssreset.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider approaching it purely in CSS, like so;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" type="text/css" /><!-- Footer Stylings -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

            #header {
                margin: 0px auto;
                width: 960px;
            }

            .logo {
                display: block;
                width: 200px;
                height: 200px;
                background-image: url('gif.gif');
            }

            .logo:hover {
                /* Some hover styling here */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <a href="https://www.google.co.uk" class="logo"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You would make your `a` tag a `block` (non-inline). I assumed the size to be 200x200 pixels. You can change that to your liking. The `a` tag will still maintain it's hyperlink properties, but display differently.

Answer (score 0):

Try reset your css before your start do anything.

```
<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        vertical-align:baseline;
    }
</style>
```

I make a simple test with css reset above and works fine. Just paste before all css in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the body:

```
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

You can eliminate this kind of problems if you use reset.css or normalize.css